# Diagnosing XA connections to Oracle via Payara 4

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jta

We are trying to setup XA connections between Payara 4 and Oracle 12 (using driver ojdbc7_g.jar) to use with JTA transactions. The configuration is such that we have 1 JDBC connection pool configured with `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource` class name and **multiple** JDBC resources pointing to the same connection pool. 
When calling the database, we stumble upon the Exception trace below. What's the best approach to diagnose such problem ?

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [i18n] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [i18n] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.eclipselink.EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.invokeInternal(EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.java:142)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.eclipselink.EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.invokeCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.java:114)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.eclipselink.EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl_$$_jvst98e_0.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl_$$_jvst98e_0.java)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:940)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAProvider.getTemplates(JPAProvider.java:66)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.<init>(JPAQuery.java:44)
    at com.goodyear.framework.i18n.dao.I18nTranslationDaoBean.findTranslationList(I18nTranslationDaoBean.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor355.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4808)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4796)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [i18n] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [i18n] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.cannotDeployWithoutPredeploy(EntityManagerSetupException.java:191)
    ... 216 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [i18n] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.eclipselink.EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.invokeInternal(EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.java:142)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.eclipselink.EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.invokeCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.java:114)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.eclipselink.EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryMethodHandler.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl_$$_jvst98e_0.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl_$$_jvst98e_0.java)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:940)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAProvider.getTemplates(JPAProvider.java:66)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.<init>(JPAQuery.java:44)
    at com.goodyear.framework.i18n.dao.I18nTranslationDaoBean.findTranslationList(I18nTranslationDaoBean.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4808)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4796)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy480.findTranslationList(Unknown Source)
    at com.goodyear.framework.i18n.dao.__EJB31_Generated__I18nTranslationDaoBean__Intf____Bean__.findTranslationList(Unknown Source)
    at com.goodyear.framework.i18n.business.I18nTranslatorServiceBean.findTranslation(I18nTranslatorServiceBean.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4808)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4796)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy482.findTranslation(Unknown Source)
    at com.goodyear.framework.i18n.business.AbstractI18nTranslator.getTranslation(AbstractI18nTranslator.java:51)
    at com.goodyear.gttd.vaadinWebClient.common.i18n.AbstractVaadinI18nTranslator.getTranslation(AbstractVaadinI18nTranslator.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [i18n] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:239)
    ... 223 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ExternalConnectionPool.startUp(ExternalConnectionPool.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    ... 221 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    ... 231 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:115)
    ... 232 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:221)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 236 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.rm.SystemResourceManagerImpl.enlistResource(SystemResourceManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:211)
    ... 238 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:660)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistXAResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:1345)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.rm.SystemResourceManagerImpl.enlistResource(SystemResourceManagerImpl.java:103)
    ... 239 more
|#]
```

I tried setting up JDBC logging using the `-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true` and configuring the appropriate loggers in the JVM setting but got no success

Answer (score 1):

Posting what we think the solution is in order to help others. Feel free to add any feedback
We had to do the following grants on the database

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_pending_transactions TO <user>;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.pending_trans$ TO <user>;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_2pc_pending TO <user>;
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_xa TO <user>;
GRANT FORCE ANY TRANSACTION TO <user>;
```

This probably allowed OJDBC driver perform a SQL call to JAVA_XA.xa_start_new procedure (found out during debugging).